# Blank variable during bash command substitution

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I am doing command substitution and saving the result to a variable. However, the results of the command contain double quotes and this is causing the variable to be empty.

When running `test="$(java -version)"` I get the following result:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

However running `echo $test` yields a blank line.

Comment: Sounds like the info is written to stderr instead of stdout as it should. You can use `test="$(java -version 2>&1)"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that `test="$(java -version)"` prints the result to the terminal directly is that `java -version` outputs to standard error (stderr), not standard output (stdout).

Because there is no stdout output (which is what `$(...)` captures), `$test` is assigned an empty string.

The solution is to redirect standard error (stderr) to standard output (stdout).

```
version=$(java -version 2>&1)
```